# Difference between object and class in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, class, object

What is the difference between Object and Class in PHP? I ask because, I don't really see the point to both of them.

Can you tell me the difference with a **good example**?

Comment: Classes are necessary in PHP because it follows the older and more static OOP paradigm. In [prototype-based languages (JavaScript, Lua)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) you do actually only need objects. So the confusion about the need for classes is not unreasoned.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I assume you have [read the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) on basic PHP OOP.

A class is what you use to **define** the properties, methods and behavior of objects. Objects are the **things you create** out of a class. Think of a class as a *blueprint*, and an object as the actual *building* you build by following the blueprint (class). *(Yes, I know the blueprint/building analogy has been done to death.)*

```
// Class
class MyClass {
    public $var;

    // Constructor
    public function __construct($var) {
        echo 'Created an object of MyClass';
        $this->var = $var;
    }

    public function show_var() {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

// Make an object
$objA = new MyClass('A');

// Call an object method to show the object's property
$objA->show_var();

// Make another object and do the same
$objB = new MyClass('B');
$objB->show_var();
```

The objects here are distinct (A and B), but they are both objects of the `MyClass` class. Going back to the blueprint/building analogy, think of it as using the same blueprint to build two different buildings.

Here's another snippet that actually talks about buildings if you need a more literal example:

```
// Class
class Building {
    // Object variables/properties
    private $number_of_floors = 5; // Each building has 5 floors
    private $color;

    // Constructor
    public function __construct($paint) {
        $this->color = $paint;
    }

    public function describe() {
        printf('This building has %d floors. It is %s in color.', 
            $this->number_of_floors, 
            $this->color
        );
    }
}

// Build a building and paint it red
$bldgA = new Building('red');

// Build another building and paint it blue
$bldgB = new Building('blue');

// Tell us how many floors these buildings have, and their painted color
$bldgA->describe();
$bldgB->describe();
```

Comment: PHP treats objects in the same way as references or handles, meaning that each variable contains an object reference rather than a copy of the entire object +1

Comment: +1 Very good and pedagogic example! Beginners often confuse the class and instance (object).

Comment: I have one question why `private $number_of_floors = 5;` and `private $color;` are called `Object variables/properties`? The `public function __construct($paint)` are called `Class constructor`. So, why not same as `Class constructor` they are called `Class variable/properties` instead of `Object variables/properties`.

Comment: @codenext: You make a good point. Other languages like C# call instance constructors, well, instance constructors, though they do this mostly because they have both instance constructors and static constructors. PHP doesn't have static constructors, but I can see how "class constructor" could be confusing to someone coming from C# or some other language.

Comment: So what's different between two objects one has more method than the other about memory?

Answer (score 2):

For the new developers:

**Class**

A class is a collection of method and variables

```
class Test{

  const t = "OK";
  var $Test;
  function TestFunction(){

  }
}
```

**Object**

Object is a instance of a class (when you want to use your class and the thing you create)

```
$test = new Test();
$test->TestFunction();//so here you can call to your class' function through the instance(Object)
```

Comment: simple and nice ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Class is a group definition containing structure and behavior, and object is anything which have structure and behavior. Object is an instance of a class, we can create multiple objects of same class.