# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context no working properly

Tags: php

```
<?php
class Functions {
    public static function extendSql($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) {
        // making the mysql connection dynamically editable
        $mysql_connect  =   mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
        $mysql_select_db =  mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    public static function whileLoop($dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $sql, $passedData) {
        $this->extendSql($dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
        $results = mysql_query($sql);       
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        echo $passedData;
        }
    }
}

Functions::whileLoop("root", "", "rand", "SELECT * FROM products",
$hello = "hi all");
?>
```

I get the following error when I execute the above code.

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
>   C:\Workspace\htdocs\Misc-2\nurbell1\core\conf\misc.php on line 13

What am I doing wrong? Obviously, $this is referenced inside the classed context in my code.

Comment: I did bro. don't you see the rates?

Comment: you upvoted the answers. but didnt accept it. upvote is different from accpting. When you accept answer, a green tick mark will come beside the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$this` in a static function, which doesn´t belong to the current instance/context, and thus is unable to use `$this`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `this` within a static function. You can use `this` only when you have an object of the class `Function`. You have to use `self` keyword to access static functions.

Change your code to `self::extendSql($dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);`

Please read this manual for more info on `self` keyword

Answer (score 1):

You can't use $this inside static methods as $this refers to the object rather than the class and you can't guarantee you have an object when a static method is called. Instead you can use "self::method()" to call a static method from within the same class.

You should read up on how PHP OOP works: [OO in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) and also what the difference between classes and objects is: [difference between object and class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837492/difference-between-object-and-class-in-php)