# How should I approach this AND is my diagram correct?

Tags: object, methods, interface

[A diagram I made in the Microsoft Paint program to better understand PHP Objects.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmfnw.jpg)

Ok, so I have been reading up on php objects recently and they are becoming quite confusing the more i get into interfaces and encapsulations. I also seem to be confusing classes and objects, but now I am fairly certain that (as my diagram shows) *Classes* are actually "bigger" than objects, if you will- that objects are just new instances (or occurrences) of a class. I am aware of the crudeness of my drawing, but can anyone out there tell me if i am on the right track? I also referred to "interface" between properties and methods because, as i understand it, interface is the process by which methods (or functions within an object) can alter properties in some way. Correct me if i'm wrong.

In the book I'm reading "Learning PHP, MySQL & JavaScript: with Jquery, CSS, and HTML5" by Robin Nixon (5 Stars), I was given an example on creating and interacting with an object. I tried to alter the code (which was originally created to deal with 'Users' on a social media network) to instead echo out to the browser that 2 objects in the "Married" class would be Maj Kanaan, the Husband ($object1) and Wife Kanaan, his Wife ($object2), but with 3 properties: first_name, last_name, and title (husand or wife). However after trying several different things i came to believe that arrays should be used in this situation or at least the __construct method, but i am missing something big here. Can anyone help? Please and thank you. I really have no code to post as an example because everything i tried was way off so i just deleted it all. All i have in my feeble explanation. Hope someone is able to work with that. Thanks again!

-your friend Maj

Comment: Hi Maj, you are asking some good questions, but unfortunately they are not the kinds of questions Stack Overflow was designed for. You seem to be understanding some parts of Object-Oriented Programming ok, and other parts not so well, making it difficult to answer here. I found a web site that might be useful to you at http://www.elated.com/articles/object-oriented-php-for-absolute-beginners/, maybe you'd like to give that a try? Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

"Classes are actually "bigger" " not certain where you are going with that but no. Quoting a title a professor forced on one of my early programming classes "Objects have class". Classes describe objects, objects are instances (actual manifestations of) classes. Classes are just a blueprint that don't do anything at all. Objects don't exist without that blueprint. You might find [Differences between object and class in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837492/difference-between-object-and-class-in-php) useful.

Interfaces are actually templates for classes. A class can [implement an interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php). It's not really a go between methods and properties, but defines a set of properties and methods that a class that implements it should have defined. Most of the time one wouldn't need to use an interface unless you are working with libraries or similar shared code.